# How to create a Model in Minds DB, search with OPEN API

Tags: php, chat, openai-api, chatgpt-api, mindsdb

I am having a table with Questions and Answers. And I need to create a Model in Minds DB with this table but unable to create. What is my need is open AI should answer my Question form my table, How can we achieve this with help of MindsDB, I am using PHP as as server code

What is my need is open AI should answer my Question form my table, How can we achieve this with help of MindsDB, I am using PHP as as server code